# O que é zero copy?

Tags: terminologia, memória

Em alguns cenários vi o termo *zero-copy*. O significa quando algo tem cópia zero? Imagino que há um ganho de desempenho quando acontece isso, mas não entendo o processo. Tem contextos diferentes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você procura algo de alta performance vários ganhos são importantes, sendo que o mais importante é evitar transporte de dados.

Eu sempre digo que se quer velocidade diminua o consumo de memória, porque isso sempre evitará transporte que custa muito caro (não é a única vantagem). Mas nem sempre é possível diminuir tanto assim.

Aí entra a situação em que é interessante que o transporte precisa ser evitado. Então toda vez que puder aproveitar um dado que está em algum lugar para uso direto sem precisar passar para outro área, talvez para atender um modelo de memória ou uma forma diferente de estruturar o mesmo dado, é interessante. Se você sabe que o dado está disponível em certo lugar, o ideal é acessar dali direto para o que precisa sem copiar para outra área. Isso é a cópia zero.

Com o *zero-copy* evita o tempo do sistema parado esperando o transporte ou ciclos de processamento necessários para processar essa cópia.

O sistema operacional pode ser o responsável por boa parte do ganho quando ele faz implicitamente ou através de alguma ferramenta específica para aproveitar o dado onde ele está de forma direta. Pode ser até mesmo transferir um arquivo pela rede sem ter que passar pela memória. Em boa parte do uso do termo é sobre IO mais eficiente.

Em alguns casos pode ser o reuso do dado que está na área do *kernel* do OS para entregar ao usuário (aplicação rodando no *user space*). Ou quando aproveita dados entre processos.

Alguns bancos de dados embarcados rápidos podem usar a técnica de acessar o dado de forma direta às páginas de memória da sua organização em vez de copiar para uma forma mais palatável para a aplicação. Isso pode aumentar o risco, mas dá um ganho importante de eficiência e pode escalar enormemente.

Você pode pegar um arquivo que vem como JSON e já acessar sem ter que reestruturar em um objeto, é *zero-copy*.

Em sua aplicação em vez de você acessar um pedaço de uma *string* em vez de criar uma outra só com essa parte está fazendo *zero-copy* porque acessa um objeto que em tese é diferente sem precisar criá-lo em outro lugar fazendo a cópia dessa parte.

O mesmo acontece quando usa uma referência em vez de transportar algo por valor.

Então o termo costuma ser usado tanto na forma como o sistema operacional trabalha com dados, como na programação como você manipula os dados na sua aplicação.

Em geral é necessário criar códigos que saibam como trabalhar em um formato de dados não tão simples. É mais ou menos o problema de decidir ser mais prático e fácil com legibilidade e obter a melhor performance. Imagine você ter que acessar os dados no JSON em vez de acessar os campos de um objeto. Em alguns contextos compensa fazer isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md)

Answer (score -1):

Com a técnica de zero-copy, você pode transferir diretamente os dados da tabela original para o sistema de destino, sem fazer cópias desnecessárias. Em vez de criar uma nova tabela temporária, os dados são passados diretamente, economizando tempo e recursos.